# The program 'alex' is required but it could not be found. Setup.lhs

Tags: bash, haskell, ghc

I am on Mac os X on a local machine, and is trying to run 
`runhaskell Setup.lhs configure --ghc`
I have been trying to install the program in several ways but I always run into the same problem

> The program 'alex' is required but it could not be found.

I have been trying to link a PATH to Alex, 
When I installed alex it showed the path being 
"Installing executable alex in /Users/xxx/Library/Haskell/ghc-8.2.1/lib/alex-3.2.3/bin"
And I can find the file there
I added this to my bash profile

```
export PATH=/Users/sven/Library/Haskell/ghc-8.2.1/lib/alex-3.2.3/bin:$PATH
```

But the message still shows up.
I installed 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: How did you install alex, do you run your program in a local environment?

Comment: Yes it is local, and I used "cabal install alex"

Comment: If you run `alex` from a terminal, does the program run?

Comment: No, actually even if I am sitting in the dir where alex is located, it just says -bash: alex: command not found

Comment: Has it been installed with the correct permissions? If you chmod +x it, then run ./alex, does that work?

Comment: Yeah! When i chmod +x it and then did ./alex -v it gave me the version number.

Comment: But it does not solve the original problem, it still says The program 'alex' is required but it could not be found.

Comment: Have you sourced the profile after editing?

Comment: It works! Holy cow... I am setting that quote as my desktop background. Thank you for all of your help!